# OledbException - Field too small to accept amount of data

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to use OleDb to insert a new record into an Access database using an SQL command into an entity called 'tblThread' (containing discussion posts, if you are wondering); this is done via a button that will take values from two controls (both being textboxes).

Here's the layout if you would like to see: https://gyazo.com/c43abf4ce055ff997b908badb57f549a 
However, after clicking on the button 'Submit Discussion', the control that inserts a new record I get an error display:

https://gyazo.com/1dbdb33290649af04f092533560b1d8c

Now here's the code for the Click event of this button:

**Please Note:**

- absDefault._memberType = 'Teacher' (in this scenario)

  ```
      private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(absDefault.conString);
      OleDbCommand objCommand = new OleDbCommand();
      objCommand.Connection = objConnection;

      if (MessageBox.Show("[Piltover]: Are you sure you would like to create this thread", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
      {
          return; // Does not execute remaining code
      }
      else if (txtTitle.TextLength == 0)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("[Piltover]: You have not created a title");
      }
      else if (mtxtDescription.TextLength == 0)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("[Piltover]: You have not added description to your thread");
      }
      else
      {
          // DBConnection class is only used within this else block and is not needed anywhere else in this form
          DataSet ds; DataRow dRow;
          DatabaseConnection objConnect = new DatabaseConnection(); // Instantiating an object from DBConnectionClass and checking if an identical title exist is much faster than the OLEDB process (shown within try block below)
          objConnect.Connection_String = absDefault.conString;
          objConnect.SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblThread"; ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
          for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
          {
              dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
              if (txtTitle.Text.ToUpper() == dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString())
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("[Piltover]: Thread already exist with the title name given");
                  return; 
              }
          }
      }
      // FIX - test to see if it works

      try
      {
          objConnection.Open();

          // Insert new thread record; avoids SQL injection
          objCommand.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO tblThread ([Title], [Description], [ID], [Username], [TeacherBool]) VALUES (@title, @desc, @id, @username, @teacherbool)");//, absDefault.newThreadMemberType);
          objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txtTitle.Text);
          objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", mtxtDescription.Text);
          objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", absDefault._idNumber);

          if (absDefault._memberType == "Teacher")
          {
              currentTeacher = new csTeacher(absDefault._idNumber, "Teacher");
              objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherbool", "True");
              objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", currentTeacher.Username);
          }
          else // else 'Student'
          {
              currentStudent = new csStudent(absDefault._idNumber, "Student");
              objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherbool", "False");
              objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", currentStudent.Username);
          }

          objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          MessageBox.Show("[Piltover]: Thread created");

          objConnection.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception Ex)
      {

          MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());
      }
  }
  ```

I am guessing the problem lies in the attribute [Description], although, I have set the data type to long text:
https://gyazo.com/2d99c945a0a0b98a1e48e8abaf043c2f

If you are wondering what contains within my DatabaseConnection class:
http://pastebin.com/RQs6qPEz

What I am confused is, my inputs are within boundaries (being under 255 characters, if that is the problem):
For example, https://gyazo.com/c43abf4ce055ff997b908badb57f549a
As you can see, the 'masked textbox' besides label 'Description' contains values less than 255 characters.

I **have** tried debugging to try and find a solution/answer.

Comment: Are you saving True/False *strings* in your database?

Comment: @LarsTech Only for the attribute [TeacherBool]. The validation rule is set to: 'True' Or 'False'

Comment: Yeah, but "True" is a string.  Just use True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Data.OleDb` allows us to use @names for parameters (and their placeholders), but it **ignores** the names and treats parameters as strictly positional. Therefore the parameters must be declared in the same order that they appear in the command text.

In your command text you specify

```
... VALUES (@title, @desc, @id, @username, @teacherbool)
```

but when you create the parameters via `AddWithValue` you do so in the following order ...

```
@title
@desc
id
@teacherbool
@username
```

... which is not the same.

You need to swap the order of declaring the @teacherbool and @username parameters in your `if` block.

Comment: Interesting. I may be late, but I will still thank you.